# How to know a defer function is called after successfully executing the function or by a panic

Tags: go, panic, defer-keyword

I need to write some business logic in defer function. Control flow in defer should be based on whether the defer is executed after the system panicked or after the successful execution of the function.

```golang
package main

import "log"

func b() {
    panic("panicked in b")
}
func a() {

    b()
}
func main() {
    defer func() {
     // If panicked 
         log.Println("panicked")
         // if called after function successfully executed
         log.Println("Success")
         /* 
            How to understand if defer is triggered by panic or after function returned successfully.
         */
    }()
    a()
    log.Println("main code")
}
```

Expected: Defer should be able to know its called by panic by any possible way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `recover` to catch the panic:

```
defer func() {
    if err := recover(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("panic")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("successful")
    }
}()
```

Comment: Also, the above code will stop the panic (the function will return successfully). If you want to continue panicking, you have to do `panic(err)`.

Comment: Yeah, Got to know that. Thanks